QGIS2ThreeJS is not loading DEM
Whenever I try to export a DEM file to QGIS2ThreeJS I get this advisory which I also attempted unsuccessfully to follow "No 3D objects were rendered? There is a compatibility issue with QGIS 3D view. You need to close QGIS 3D view(s) and restart QGIS to use this preview."

Please specify which QGIS version you are using.

3.38.3 Grenoble

A few days ago, some of my students had the same problem when working with the Qgis2threejs module in the latest version of QGIS (3.38.3 Grenoble).
We have additionally (in parallel) installed the long-term version of QGIS 3.34.11 'Prizren'.
In LTE version in Qgis2threejs, everything renders normally.
In our case, it worked.
You can try it too.
Please let me know helped it or not.

Hi Alexander, thanks for the suggestion. I installed the LTE version and Qgis2threejs worked fine.
